# Interfacing C++ iterators from C

Tags: c++, c

I'm writing a C backend for a C++ library and I want the C code to be able to iterate over the individual items of a forward iterator. In C++ the code which iterates over the items looks like this:

```
auto rng = wks.range(XLCellReference("A1"), XLCellReference("Q1"));
for (auto& cell : rng) {
   // do something with "cell" 
}
```

Now I want to export this code so that it is accessible from C. I'd like to be able to iterate over the items from C using a set of functions like this:

```
void *startiteration(void *cpp_obj);
void *getnextitem(void *cpp_obj, void *iter);
void finishiteration(void *cpp_obj, void *iter);
```

I'd imagine `startiteration()` to return an iterator pointer to the C code which would then be passed along with the C++ object pointer for all successive calls to `getnextitem()` and `finishiteration()`.

But the problem here is that I can easily pass pointers of objects created in C++ using `new` between C and C++ code but I don't see how I could do the same with iterators since the iterators are returned by a class method and I don't think there's any way to turn the iterator into a pointer that I could pass to C code which would then pass it back to C++ during the iteration. Also, I don't know how I would "free" such an iterator.

Does anybody have some tips how I can iterate over a C++ forward iterator from C code? How should this be implemented?

**EDIT**

Implementation based on Silvio's suggestions:

```
struct myiter
{
    XLCellIterator begin;
    XLCellIterator end;
};
    
void *xlsx_startiteration(void *handle, int idx)
{
    XLDocument *doc = (XLDocument *) handle;
    XLWorkbook wb = doc->workbook();
    auto wks = wb.worksheet(wb.sheetNames()[idx-1]);    
    XLCellRange cr = wks.range(XLCellReference("A1"), XLCellReference("Q1"));   
    myiter *it = new myiter();
                
    it->begin = std::begin(static_cast<XLCellRange*>(cr));
    it->end = std::end(static_cast<XLCellRange*>(cr));
 
    return it;
}
```

Comment: You could allocate the iterator on the heap and return a pointer to it. Or, if you know what this particular range's iterator is, it might be convertible to a pointer.

Comment: How much data does the iterator store? It may be convenient to just return the whole iterator, `for(struct foo_iter it = foo_begin(&foo); item = foo_next(&it); )`.

Comment: Don't know about the data stored by the iterator as I didn't write the C++ library. The iterator I'm talking about is `XLCellIterator` of the OpenXLSX library. It allows to iterate over a range of Excel cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> auto rng = wks.range(XLCellReference("A1"), XLCellReference("Q1"));
> for (auto& cell : rng) {
>    // do something with "cell" 
> }
> ```

I like doing 1:1 relationship between C++ and C. The following code outputs 3 lines `var=1` `var=2` `var=3`.

By wrapping the objects inside structures, the C side only forward declarations of structures and pointers. The C++ side sees all the rest. Additionally, C side will get a warning when passing invalid pointer to the wrong function.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
typedef int do_not_know_what_is_the_type;
typedef std::vector<do_not_know_what_is_the_type> XLCellRange;
typedef XLCellRange::iterator XLCellIterator;


// header file

// C side
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

struct wks_range_it_s;
void wks_range_it_inc(struct wks_range_it_s *);
bool wks_range_it_ne(struct wks_range_it_s *, struct wks_range_it_s *);
do_not_know_what_is_the_type wks_range_it_deref(struct wks_range_it_s *);
void wks_range_it_destruct(struct wks_range_it_s *);

struct wks_range_s;
struct wks_range_s *wks_range_construct();
void wks_range_destruct(struct wks_range_s *);
struct wks_range_it_s *wks_range_begin(struct wks_range_s *);
struct wks_range_it_s *wks_range_end(struct wks_range_s *);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus

// C++ side
struct wks_range_s {
    XLCellRange rng;
};

struct wks_range_it_s {
    XLCellIterator it;
};

extern "C"
void wks_range_it_inc(struct wks_range_it_s *t) {
    ++t->it;
}

extern "C"
bool wks_range_it_ne(struct wks_range_it_s *a, struct wks_range_it_s *b) {
    return a->it != b->it;
}

extern "C"
do_not_know_what_is_the_type wks_range_it_deref(struct wks_range_it_s *t) {
    return *t->it;
}

extern "C"
void wks_range_it_destruct(struct wks_range_it_s *t) {
    delete t;
}

extern "C"
struct wks_range_s *wks_range_construct() {
     // return new struct wks_range_s(wks.range(XLCellReference("A1"), XLCellReference("Q1")));
    return new wks_range_s{{1,2,3}};
}

extern "C"
void wks_range_destruct(struct wks_range_s *t) {
     delete t;
}

extern "C"
struct wks_range_it_s *wks_range_begin(struct wks_range_s *t) {
    return new wks_range_it_s{t->rng.begin()};
}

extern "C"
struct wks_range_it_s *wks_range_end(struct wks_range_s *t) {
    return new wks_range_it_s{t->rng.end()};
}

#endif

int main() {
   // C code example
   struct wks_range_s *rng = wks_range_construct();
   // Almost 1:1 relationship with C++ range loop.
   for(struct wks_range_it_s *begin = wks_range_begin(rng),
                *end = wks_range_end(rng);
                wks_range_it_ne(begin, end) ? 1 : (
                    // Yes, I'm sneaky.
                    wks_range_it_destruct(begin),
                    wks_range_it_destruct(end),
                    0); 
                wks_range_it_inc(begin)
            ) {
        do_not_know_what_is_the_type var = wks_range_it_deref(begin);
        // do something with var here?
        printf("var=%d\n", var);
    }  
    wks_range_destruct(rng);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works and it's exactly what I needed. Thanks man, you made my day! I never would have figured that out on my own. Big thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Forward iterators in C++ are [regular](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/regular), which means they can be copied. In fact, in our case, we would only need to move them. Specifically, assuming the type of the iterator in question is `I`, then `startiteration` could do something like this.

```
struct Range {
  I begin;
  I end;
};

void* startiteration(void* cpp_obj) {
  Range* my_range = new Range();
  my_range->begin = std::begin(*static_cast<MyCppType*>(cpp_object));
  my_range->end = std::end(*static_cast<MyCppType*>(cpp_object));
  return my_range;
}
```

Just because the forward iterator is originally returned by value doesn't prohibit us from putting it into a pointer, either directly or indirectly. In our case, we grab both the beginning and the end and store them in a (heap-allocated) structure. Then `finishiteration`, of course, would be responsible for `delete`ing the constructed range object.

Comment: Thanks, sounds good! I've tried to implement it like that but I'm getting the error that `XLCellRange` can't be cast to `XLCellRange*`. I've pasted my implementation based on your suggestions in the OP. Could you check what's wrong there? Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's no need for a cast if the data is already of the correct type. You're trying to cast a `XlCellRange` to `XlCellRange*`. Since you've already got the right (C++) type, just call `std::begin` on that

Comment: Thanks, but now the compiler complains about the line `myiter *it = new myiter()`, returning Visual C++ error C2280: "attempting to reference a deleted function" Any idea how to fix that?